# How to disable forced https redirection in Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, https, azure-functions

I have an azure function and I created couple rest api request via httpClient to external http api.

External resource doesn't have https address so I can use only http.
All httpClient request goes to https address.

How can I disable this https redirection in Azure Function application?

I have my own Startup class inherited from FunctionStartup, but I didn't find any solution how to disable forced https redirection by code.

Comment: You need to configure the API you are calling to allow for non-HTTPS traffic. `HttpClient` doesn't change your request to use HTTPS, the service you are calling does.

Comment: @Andy I can call this api from postman and I can use http in address. So the problem with azure function middleware which redirects all my http requests to https by default.

Comment: Change your URL from HTTPS to HTTP.

Comment: you aren't seeing the redirect that is happening. In PostMan: In Settings, turn off "Automatically follow redirects" and you will see the same error.

Comment: @Andy maybe you doesn't understand my question. I turned off redirects in postman and http works. Let me explain. I use http api and it works without any redirects. But when I call this http api from my azure function, function middleware tries using https instead http. Api doesn't have https endpoint, only http.

Comment: @Andy I need to call http from my azure function. I need to disable forced https.